# how to convert image button in css configurable button

Tags: css, image, button, magento-1.7, configurable

How can I convert this image button so it willl be a css configurable button? 
In the underneath code both image submit button and css submit button are present. The image send button is the original button and working. My goal is to convert this button in a working css button....at the moment the css button is visible but not working. The imagebutton is working as a send button....how can I achieve this? thx!

```
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Login Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="confirmation" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" name="confirmation" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="confirmation" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons-set">
        <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <p class="back-link"><a href="<?php echo $this->escapeUrl($this->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="back-link"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a></p>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
        <button class="form-button-alt submit" onclick="setsubmit('<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" type="button"><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></button>
    </div>
```

Comment: which button do you want to convert in CSS?
do you have a picture or else ? anyway you can easily go to this amazing website for you purpose :-) : - http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ - http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/ - http://css3button.net/ - http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/ choose the one you prefere and you'll be fine :-)

Comment: hi there thank you for your reply. this is the link:

http://www.badhabits.eu/shop/customer/account/create/

the blue image button is working (send) and the original of the template. The grey button is one I created but is not working (send). I want the grey CSS button instead of the blue image button...thx for you help