# how can I change magento image button (add new adress) into a html button

Tags: magento, button

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add New Address') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getAddAddressUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add New Address') ?></span></span></button>
```

I tried something `<input type="submit" title="Add New Address" value="Add New Address" />`
but only the button shows up but is not linking to the add new address form

Comment: I guess you are referring to your same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16111882/2362921 ? You don't need to change <button> to <input>, you can style both with css. Look into your styles.css to get a feeling

Comment: styling with css styles.css is not possible because it is an image button and not a css configural button

Comment: problem solved by meself <button class="form-button-alt Add New Address" onclick="window.location=('<?php echo $this->getAddAddressUrl()?>')" type="button"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add new address') ?></span></button>

Comment: You don't need to trust answers from people you don't know, but you might accept to go for hints they give and validate it yourself. But it's ok for me, if you prefer editing all your templates instead of glancing inside your example ccs files, go for it.